# Arthur-Merlin protocol

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, protocols

I recently learned about the Arthur-Merlin protocol, and we defined the complexity classes $AM,MA$.

We have also seen that there exists a theorem stating that $AMAMAM...AM=AM$, however we have not formally defined $AMAMAMAM...AM$.

We did give a brief definition for it as a protocol, but i would like to see a formal definition **without protocols**, just like $AM$ and $MA$ (and $MAM$)

A definition for $AMA$ should suffice for me, just to get the hang of how it should look.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AMA$ is basically a 3-round interactive proof system where the verifier (Arthur) is only allowed to send randomness to the prover (Merlin).
I haven't seen such an explicit definition yet, but I think we can formulate it as follows.
The first round of AM[3] starts with Merlin sending a message $m_1$ to Arthur. In the second round, Arthur sends randomness $r$ to Merlin, which is followed by the final third round in which Merlin sends a message $m_2$. Arthur then decides to accept/reject using deterministic polynomial-time verifier $V$.

I think we can define the class as follows.
**Definition:** $L ∈ AMA$ if there exists a poly-time deterministic algorithm $V$ such that:

- If $x \in L \;(|x| = n)$ then $\exists P. Pr_{r \in \{0,1\}^{p(n)}} \left( V(x, m_1, r, m_2) = 1 \right) \ge 2/3$ where $\; m_1 = P(x),\; 
  m_2 = P(x, r)$
- If $x \notin L \;(|x| = n)$ then $\forall P. Pr_{r \in \{0,1\}^{p(n)}} \left( V(x, m_1, r, m_2) = 1 \right) \le 1/3$ where $\; m_1 = P(x),\; 
  m_2 = P(x, r)$

Note the prover $P$ is a function $P: \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{q(n)}$, where $q(n)$ is a polynomial.

See: Computational Complxity by Arora-Barak's section 8.1.

Comment: Interesting... Following this idea, wouldn't we need to have $\exists P_1,P_2:...$ where $m_1=P_1(x)$,$m_2=P_2(x,r)$?

Comment: A single prover is enough as it’s a mapping. It can capture all the interaction’s output in a single map/function.

Comment: oh, and I have noticed that you gave the definition for $MAM$ as there are two prover rounds and one verifier round. right?

Comment: Switching it around doesn't seem problematic with this idea anyways, so thanks!

Comment: It’s a bit confusing. Some sources define that AM[k] should start with Arthur, but then there are sources which say that AM[3] has to start with Merlin as we are allowed to transfer 3 messages, and if we start with Arthur then third message would be redundant (why?). E.g., see Wikipedia of Arthur Merlin Protocol. I just chose the one I found logical.

Comment: hmm... right. I should have asked about $AMAM$ then! (this solution works for it too) :)